# Update multiple Umbraco sites through windows application

Tags: asp.net, content-management-system, umbraco, umbraco7

We are using umbraco 7.1.3

As per client's requirement we need to create more then 550 Umbraco CMS sites for different cities with same template and asp.net user control which access data from one master database.

So we created one windows application that will create 550+ sites as per city name under one Non-Umbraco root site.
We also managed to create different Umbraco database for each site is created and moved published code under to Non-Umbraco root site and convert to application and also updated Web.config file for each site dynamically.

After that when-ever we found that our logic or UI was not correct we also update DLL, ASCX user controls and CSS to all sites through same window application.

Till now everything was going smooth, but now we have one major change and that contains new document type, template, macro and new menu needs to be added dynamically. Updating published code through windows application was easy but we don't found any way to make update Umbraco database of 500+ sites through another application.

Some websites are already updated through respective sites owners, so without affected any existing changes we need to add new macro, content, document type and menu for each site and we don't know in which Umbraco database we need to enter records?

Had already posted the same in umbraco issue tracker [#U4-7105](http://issues.umbraco.org/issue/U4-7105)
Also in Umbraco forums [#71443](https://our.umbraco.org/forum/umbraco-7/using-umbraco-7//71443-update-multiple-umbraco-sites-through-windows-application#comment-71443)

Thanks & Regard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like an interesting case!

If you want to migrate items that are in the database such as document types, templates and macros you would most likely need to get a product like [Courier](https://our.umbraco.org/projects/umbraco-pro/umbraco-courier-2). I can see that due to license costs this could be an issue for you with 500+ sites.

Another option could be to take a look at [uSync](https://our.umbraco.org/projects/developer-tools/usync) to see if it does what you need. I don't have much experience with this package but from the looks of it, it seems like it is handling all the database bits - and everything else (files on the file system) would be handled by your application just as it is right now.

Comment: First of all Thanks @Claus for suggestion and I apologies for late response. We looked at you suggestion it looks good, then we also got reply form [Umbraco Issue Tracker](http://issues.umbraco.org/issue/U4-7105).

For now we decided to go with traditional process(deletion & regeneration)

Comment: Yes - Umbraco as a Service actually does exactly what you are trying to do here, but on a managed platform. From what I read in your question it seemed like a non-viable solution suggesting you move 500+ sites to UaaS when you clearly already have a working hosting setup.
If you however do at some point come to consider using the platform, a lot of your work here will already be done using baselines for deployment of child sites.